# Django: Redirect from function doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Anyone can tell me, why my redirect doesn't work? I can see "SHOULD REDIRECT 2" in my terminal, but somehow the redirect never happens. Redirect import is there.

helpers.py

```
def get_reserved_items_or_redirect(request):
    session_order_reference = request.session.get('order_reference')
    if request.session.get('order_reference'):
        reserved_items = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
            order_reference=session_order_reference
        )
        print("session_order_reference: ", session_order_reference)
        if not reserved_items:
            print( "SHOULD REDIRECT 1")
            return redirect('website:index')
    else:
        print( "SHOULD REDIRECT 2")
        return redirect('website:index')
```

views.py

```
class CheckoutView(TemplateView):
    # To check make an order

    template_name = "checkout/checkout_new.html"

    # make it a decorator
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        get_reserved_items_or_redirect(request)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the response from calling `get_reserved_items_or_redirect` in `dispatch`. (But note you never return the reserved items anyway...)

Comment: Ah so the redirect wouldn't work from the function I call? I have to initiate it directly in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `CheckoutView`, you only call `get_reserved_items_or_redirect(request)`.
To make it works, just refactor your dispatch method to return the return value of this method.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if some_value: # Check if you need to perform redirect
        return get_reserved_items_or_redirect(request)
    else: # If redirect is not required
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Okay I understand, just one more question do I have to write `return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` then somehow in my helper function? Otherwise, the template doesn't show if no redirect occurs.

Comment: Yes, you have to check when perform redirect and when it isn't required, return the `super...`. I've just edited an answer, please check it.